# rosdep initialization error

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 a day back. And I'm trying to install ROS. I have installed ros-groovy-destop-full. When I try to initialise rosdep, I get error.

> sudo rosdep init

> ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
> ...
> Website may be down.

But when I copy the address and paste into web browser, the links works. I am running behind proxy (with username/password), so it may be problem of proxy. But I have put proxy details in /etc/apt/apt.conf and apt-get is working fine behind proxy. How do I resolve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54150/rosdep-initialization-error/) by [nehchal](https://answers.ros.org/users/4032/nehchal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nehchal](https://answers.ros.org/users/4032/nehchal/) on 2013-02-03**:
$ sudo rosdep init

ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.

**Comment by [cmansley](https://answers.ros.org/users/803/cmansley/) on 2014-04-25**:
As of today, it seems to work with proxies just fine. The key hint is that you need to use
`sudo -E rosdep init`
to propagate the environmental variables.

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2014-09-10**:
@cmansley : I get the same error even with the ' sudo -E rosdep init ' Just did a clean install of ROS Indigo, but still can't rosdep init. Same error: ERROR: cannot download default sources list from: ... Website may be down. Any other ideas?

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2016-05-15**:
I still get this error in 2016 (ubuntu 14.04.2 + ROS indigo). Has anyone been able to find a definitive a solution for this? Proxies didn't solved the problem for me, I still get this error when I try any "rosdep init", "sudo rosdep init" or "sudo -E rosdep init".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried to configure a system wide proxy in /etc/environment? Add something similar to this to /etc/environment

```
http_proxy=http://[user:password@]proxy_server:port/
https_proxy=https://[user:password@]proxy_server:port/
```

I guess rosdep init directly downloads the file from the link and does not use apt to get the file. So your proxy config for apt will not be used...

---

Originally posted by [sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1013/sebastian/) with karma: 76 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-09-10**:
Hi, I have followed your instructions ; but still the error exists...
Follow the link http://answers.ros.org/question/54924/groovy-error-installation/
Which told us to TRY AGAIN ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-14**:
I opened a ticket https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/271 to add support for being behind a proxy.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2014-02-24**:
Can 'rosdep init / update'  be done without connecting to net?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-05-22**:
They both need network resources so no they can not be done offline.

**Comment by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on 2017-03-29**:
For example, if my rasp has:

- Username: pi
- Password: raspberry
- Proxy_server: 192.168.1.100
- Port: 808

I will add:

```
http_proxy=http://pi:raspberry@192.169.1.100:808/
https_proxy=https://pi:raspberry@192.169.1.100:808/
```

Is it correct format?

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2017-04-10**:
Yes. It reads ok.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo -E rosdep init

This command worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [rohanchauhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26833/rohanchauhan/) with karma: 41 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shoeb Ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/33157/shoeb-ahmed/) on 2018-03-16**:
worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This wound up being the solution on one system I was using (Jetson TX1 w/ Ubuntu 16.04)

sudo c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs

---

Originally posted by [zqpm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25272/zqpm/) with karma: 151 on 2017-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khaled@neo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29432/khaled@neo/) on 2017-03-06**:
thank you, this works for me on a Jetson TX1 too

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-03-06**:
More info for TX1 users: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/12894

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2017-04-26**:
Thanks a lot, it worked for the jetson TX2.

**Comment by [pablini27](https://answers.ros.org/users/34968/pablini27/) on 2018-05-04**:
Also worked for me, using the Jetson TX2. Thanks a lot

**Comment by [shimjs747](https://answers.ros.org/users/36594/shimjs747/) on 2018-07-23**:
thanks!! it was good :)